# Geometry Nodes - Failed to Apply error "Transform curve to mesh in order to apply constructive modifiers"

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I am working on printing a model that has the below chains generated with geometry nodes.
However when I try to apply the geometry nodes to turn them to mesh I get a failed to apply geometry nodes result.

Can these be turned into mesh?  I am adding a file so that maybe someone can turn them to mesh for me or at least resolve the problem. Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You could try to make instances Real

Comment: How is it done please? Never heard of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert *Realize instances* at the end of the node tree:

[image]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> Visual Geometry to mesh

Comment: I did not find visual geometry to mesh when I pressed ctrl + A but went to Object - Apply  - visual geometry to mesh and it worked.  Thanks Very much.

Comment: Any idea on how to make this work when the new geometry is not generated by instancing, but rather through *Curve to Mesh* and *Extrude Mesh*?

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea you cannot make mesh in curve object. Make mesh object and insert curve via object data node.