# Geometry nodes fail to apply "Transform curve to mesh in order to apply constructive modifiers" generated geometry

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I get a "Transform curve to mesh in order to apply constructive modifiers" error when I try to apply the geometry nodes. I'm using a curve to generate geometry in a similar fashion to what's being done in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269416/geometry-nodes-failed-to-apply-error-transform-curve-to-mesh-in-order-to-appl), but *Realize Instances* won't cut here because the geometry is being generated through *Curve To Mesh* and *Extrude Mesh*.

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only apply a modifier if the underlying object is a mesh.

You can convert the object to a mesh with *Object > Convert > Mesh* (or with <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Mesh*), and then the modifier can be applied.

But if you want to convert directly the curve where you use the *Geometry Nodes* modifier, then you could create a cube, use the modifier there and include the curve with `Object Info`. This will allow the modifier to be applied to the cube, and your curve will still be a curve:

[image]